75W over x8 slot PCIe
I have a custom x8 PCIe card PCBA I am plugging into an x16 PCIe slot on an off-the-shelf motherboard. Would I be able to get the full 75W (5x 1.1A 12V and 1x 3A 3.3V) onto my x8 card?
I am reading that I'd need to plug in a x16 card in order to get 75W, but I am not seeing why this would be the case.

Please give a link to the source of "reading that I'd need to plug in a x16 card in order to get 75W."

See here: https://greatpcreview.com/guides/where-does-pcie-cables-go/
As well as reading through: PCI Express Card Electromechanical Specification

TL;DR; To conform to the PCIe spec, a x8 device should not draw more than 25W from the PCIe slot.

Slots less than x16 are not required to be capable of providing more than 25W to the attached cards. Not all x16 slots are capable of providing 75W either.
A x8 card is capable of being plugged into a slot smaller than x16. Therefore by design a x8 card should be capable of operating on the 25W alone. If not, a 12V 6-pin (or bigger) power connector should be used to make up the difference.

For a non-conformant device, all bets are off. You can do what you want but don't be surprised if it doesn't work or breaks something in the process. This is not recommended at all.
There's no electrical reason why a x8 device plugged into a 75W capable x16 slot can't draw 75W if it negotiates it with the motherboard. After all the power pins are the same, and on many cheap motherboards don't have real capabilities for limiting the power delivered electronically (beyond self destruction of the board!).
However it is entirely possible that you will end up disappointed and things don't work as expected - again, this is why you should conform to the spec.

To understand, if we are to plug our x8 board into a x16 slot motherboard, we should be able to draw 75W? So there's no reason to respin the board to make it x16, correct?

@dual1ty The answer is saying exactly opposite, you might not be able to draw 75W, because the hardware does not expect a 8x card to draw 75W, there might not be 75W even available to any card after all the other cards have been told they can get what they requested.

@dual1ty If you want to be sure things will work, conform to the spec. Do not make a x8 card that draws more than 25W from the motherboard.

For a one off test board, you can try it and see if it works, but there's no guarantee it will work.

A 8x card must negotiate wanting up to 25W if it identifies itself as high power device.
The host will know it's not a 16x card and the system (OS, hardware, drivers) may refuse to configure and initialize it if 8x card says it wants more than 25W.
So you cannot blindly draw 75W without asking if it is possible so the hardware can prepare for that or make sure which devices it can power or not.
Same thing with USB. You cannot draw 1A without asking, or there may be a situation where four devices draw 1A each and they are all on a hub that is on single port that cannot provide 4A.

Does the host know via the PRSNT signal, or how does it know that we are plugging in a non-x16 card? I am trying to understand how a host would know whether we are plugging in a x8 or a x16 card for the host then to either source 75W or 25W only.

Yes the present sense pins. The host will know you plugged in a 8x card so it can run the link at 8x. Even a 16x cannot draw 75W without it being initialized and configured and if there is some part of the system that calculates that all the cards draw too much it won't initialize the ones that would cause the limit to exceed.

I appreciate it. I was suspecting that it'd have something to do with the PRSNT, as the specifications indicates to be connecting traces to the furthest PRSNT pad. I just was not able to find any documentation that explicitly states that host is using the PRSNT pins of the card to determine what size card has been plugged in. Do you know if this is stated somewhere so that I can reference it?

@dual1ty Sorry, I misspoke. The PRSNT pins are to indicate a card has been fully inserted, no matter the length, but the PRSNT pins make contact when both ends of any size card have been properly inserted. The link width is of course determined at some point, when it becomes obvious that a x8 card will not be able to form a x16 link the system will know it.

That does make sense, but do we know how the system/motherboard determines whether a x8 or a x16 card is inserted? I can believe that this is true, but I'd really to understand how the system determines this.

@dual1ty If you can't negotiate a x16 link with 16 lanes because you have only 8, you don't have a x16 card. The lines will be missing termination as they are unconnected. Your card must also tell it supports up to 8x link and also must say it does not support 16x. The link training and assingment sequence makes it apparent that your card sends on only 8 lanes which the host chipset can see even if it sends 16 lanes to 16x slot.

To dive a little deeper into one of your comments:

That does make sense, but do we know how the system/motherboard determines whether a x8 or a x16 card is inserted? I can believe that this is true, but I'd really to understand how the system determines this.

The system determines the PCIe width during link negotiation. The first step in link negotiation is for the root complex and endpoint to send a pulse on each lane and measure the RC time constant of the pulse to determine if the lane is terminated. Once it detects at least one terminated lane, it moves to the next step in link negotiation and can pass the number of terminated lanes it found upstream for the motherboard to determine how much power to allocate to the device. If a x8 card is plugged into a x16 slot, 8 of the lanes are not terminated and the motherboard knows right off the bat what size the card is. Whether the motherboard will actually use that information to limit the power the device can use depends on the motherboard you're using.
Generally, I would advise if you are building a PCBA that uses PCIe, it is a good idea to become very familiar with the spec (which has this information). Although I understand it's rather expensive to get access to the spec, the cost of making a PCIe device that fails because you went without it could be higher...

I appreciate the information, as I did want to go a bit deeper. Is this knowledge part of a specification I can reference to? I haven't found this in the "PCI Express Card Electromechanical Specification" and some of the other specification the prior referenced, unless I have a shortened version.

The link negotiation information is in the "PCI Express Base Specification." I don't remember the exact section number off the top of my head, but in the physical layer section there's some stuff about link width negotiation and the link training and status state machine (LTSSM). The state that does the lane detection is called detect.active.
